# How to choose the right i-frame with webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, captcha

to everyone.
I have the next url: "https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies"
I need to click by webdriver the audio-button icon on captcha.
[image]
I can click captcha box, but can`t access to audio button. 
Here is my code:

```
import os, urllib.request, requests, datetime, time, random, ssl, json, codecs, csv, urllib
import os.path
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image


proxy = "94.79.52.207:8080" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
chromedriver = "chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver,       chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1050, 740)
driver.get("https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies")


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox']/div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark']"))).click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#rc-imageselect > div.rc-footer > div.rc-controls > div.primary-controls")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-audio-button"]'))).click()
```

Comment: have you tried the xPath in my answer?

Comment: Add the relevant HTML to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just changed the iFrame to XPath... like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@title="recaptcha challenge"]')))
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Perfect approach to switch frames.